# Trying to send tweet messages to Azure Service bus message queue but the message content is empty

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to send the twitter messages for a specific hashtag to azure service bus message queue using the azure logic app. But the message content received by message queue is empty! not sure which part is wrong?[image]

Comment: i could get data by setting the individual fields of the tweet message in the content section but when setting the "Tweet Message" payload it does not pass anything!

Comment: Did you mean the Logic app was triggered, but in the output of "When a new tweet is posted" no message in the "TweetText"?

Comment: not the tweet text, I was using the whole tweet payload field.

Answer (score 1):

The content is null because the no tweet associateds with `event1` are posted, if you run the logic app manually you will see the tip: `To see it work now, create a new tweet.`

[image]

As the official doc said, you could

> use a hashtag that is popular enough to generate new tweets in the
>   chosen interval.

So I test the same tag #Azure(Suggested value) as the doc, and get the values. And you can see they have same content and sessionID. For more details, you could refer to this site: [Connect to Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email#connect-to-twitter).

[image]

[image]

[image]